# iOS 10 UIWebView rendering issue CSS with jquerymobile and Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, uiwebview, ios10

I develop an SPA Webapp with cordova since many year ago for iPad, started with ios 6.0, that I maintain by upgrade JavaScript library, Cordova iOS, plugin etc. for each Apple upgrade of iOS.

It is the first time during many years I have a very strange Rendering problem with iPad on iOS 10, iOS 10.0.2, iOS 10.1 but not with iOS 9 and earlier.

I think it due to CSS rendering because javascript seems work.
Background do not appear! the screen is cut into quater!
I make some screen shot, the good screen on the left side and the strange on the right.

[screen 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g5Iq.png)

[screen 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEeMm.png)

When I restart the application everything returns to normal.

I continue to use UiWebview because `WKWebview` have many security police at this time. And I need the very Fast virtual FTS3 of Websql engine inside.

I actually use cordova iOS platform `4.2.0`  but I tried with `4.2.1` I have the same occasional rendering problem. The main javascript framework is `jquerymobile 1.4.5`

The plugin used is:

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3  ( I trie also the least without succeed)
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.
```

Anyone is having the same problem ?
Any workaround ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No  I don't find.   Sometime  this trouble come  again.